# finding values for determinant to equal 0

Tags: matrices, determinant

I needed to find for which values of $\lambda$ the matrix is singular.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1-\lambda & 0 & 3 \\
        1 & 1-\lambda & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & -\lambda \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

**What I did** : Compared the determinant of the matrix to zero and ended up with this:
$$-\lambda (1-2\lambda+\lambda^2)+6=0 $$
(tried 2 different ways of calculating the determinant but ended up with the same expression). How do I solve it from here?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes it's supposed to be -\lambda. I feel silly... really sorry. first time posting here. thanks for your patience.

Comment: No need to feel silly, probably I have had more troubles with minus signs than you. The little correction turns the thing from an unpleasant cubic to a tame one.

Comment: You are trying to find the eigenvalues of a certain matrix. Can you type in the matrix separately? Typos are less likely if you do that.

Comment: If you are now able to solve the problem, you're encouraged to post an answer and, later, accept it. This keeps the question from popping up over and over again.

Comment: talked with the publisher of this question and he admitted of having a typo... the (2,2) number is supposed to be $1+\lambda$ ... will post my answer soon.

Comment: Going past your issue with the error, you would have a cubic equation to solve and can resort to one of the methods here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function or use a computer algebra system (Mathematica, Maxima, MapleV) or Matlab or WolframAlpha.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your expression for the determinant is correct, Wolfram Alpha says the approximate roots are $2.53766$ and $-.268828 \pm 1.51397 i$.